# Estimation and hypothesis testing for the difference in squared bias for two random variables

Tags: estimation, bias, central-limit-theorem

**My Question:**

Let $X_t$ and $Y_t$ denote two time-series random variables, both of which are estimates of the random variable $\theta_t$. Let $U_t = X_t - \theta_t$, and $V_t = Y_t - \theta_t$. The bias of each variable is thus $\mathbb{E} U_t$ and $\mathbb{E} V_t$. I'm interested in estimation and hypothesis testing on the difference in squared bias, that is:
\begin{equation}
\gamma = (\mathbb{E} U_t)^2 - (\mathbb{E} V_t)^2
\end{equation}
I thought this would be a fairly common problem, but some googling has not revealed much at all. I'm interested in any suggestions users have for estimating $\gamma$, and conducting hypothesis tests.

**My Current Approach:**

Using the difference in squares, we get:
\begin{equation}
\gamma = (\mathbb{E} U_t - \mathbb{E} V_t)(\mathbb{E} U_t + \mathbb{E} V_t)
\end{equation}
Let $\bar{X} = \frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T X_t$, then we have the estimator:
\begin{equation}
\hat{\gamma} = (\bar{U} - \bar{V})(\bar{U} + \bar{V})
\end{equation}
Assuming that $U_t$ and $V_t$ obey the minimum conditions for Central Limit Theorem (CLT), e.g. bounded moments and weak dependence, the sample means converge in probability to their corresponding moments, and so using Slutsky's theorem $\hat{\gamma} \rightarrow \gamma$ (in probability).

A CLT also applies, but not universally. Let:
\begin{equation}
A_t = (\bar{U} + \bar{V})(U_t - V_t)
\end{equation}
Given weak dependence and bounded moments on $U_t - V_t$, we have $\sqrt{T} \bar{A} \rightarrow \mathcal{N}$ via Cramer's theorem (see eg Davidson (1994) Theorem 22.14), *but only if* $\bar{U} + \bar{V} \rightarrow c \neq 0$ in probability. In the case where $c = 0$, we have $\sqrt{T} \bar{A} \rightarrow 0$ in probability.

In a finite sample simulation, it is straightforward to see that if $c$ is set close to zero the finite sample distribution is much pointier than a Normal (which makes sense, since the statistic is converging in distribution to a Dirac delta function). Of course, in the real world, we don't know the true value of $c$, so we don't know if inference using the Normal will be appropriate or not.

So, any ideas on how I can improve this estimator so that I can safely do inference for any $c$?

(Final note: we could also use $B_t = (\bar{U} - \bar{V})(U_t + V_t)$ and examine $\sqrt{T} \bar{B}$, but this simply alters the restriction so that it is $\bar{U} - \bar{V} \rightarrow c_2 \neq 0$. It doesn't solve the problem.)

Comment: If you are only interested in testing $\gamma = 0$, it would likely be better to test $|\mathbb{E}U_t| - |\mathbb{E}V_t| = 0$ than the difference between the squares of the two terms, as the tails of the distribution of the former will likely be smaller than the tails of the distribution of the latter.

Comment: @jbowman Unfortunately I'm interested specifically in the difference of squares, not just for its own sake, but also in the larger context of an MSE estimator, where for my specific application it just so happens to prove useful to split the MSE estimation problem up into the difference in variance and difference in squared bias pieces.